# Can't we see electrons without affecting their movements?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, double-slit-experiment

Can't we see electrons without affecting their movements? I was thinking about the double slit experiment and something is writing on Feynman's book like photons can affect their movements too. But I am not talking about just the photons, what else we can think?

Comment: Do you know about the [uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle), and the [observer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics))?

Comment: What are you going to see them with?  They are too small to be seen with photons, and any detector that detects their electric field must do so by interacting with that electric field, which will move them during that detection.

Answer (score 1):

The electron is an elementary particle, one of the building blocks of the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics, and can be studied accurately with quantum mechanical tools.

At the quantum mechanical level there exist particles and interactions of these particles  between themselves . Thus to "Know an electron" one has to use  the electromagnetic interaction.  The electron also interacts with the weak interaction and with the gravitational one, but these last are too weak to be used instead of photons. Look at the [table of strengths.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html)

The double slit experiment is the complex electromagnetic interaction of the electron with the fringe electric fields of the slits, a solution of "electron plus two slits a certain distance apart and of certain width". This can be visualized with the exchange of a virtual photon between the electron and the slits , which determines the direction and t[he spot it will find itself on the screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles).

Another way to "know" an electron was involved in an interaction is in lepton number conservation and the balance in interactions with many particles.

[Here is how a](https://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCwebsite/index.htm)n electron is detected in a bubble chamber:

[image: electron]

It is interacting with the magnetic field which is perpendicular to the picture, the radius is consistent with the mass of the electron, which is losing momentum by inumerable small electromagnetic scatters with the atoms of the bubble chamber, the small ionization dots.

It is all electromagnetic, whether virtual ( [mathematical model)](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) or real photons being involved. Interaction means that the energy momentum four vector of the electron will be affected, so there is no detection of electrons without interactions.

Comment: So your answer to the title question is no?

Comment: @AaronStevens yes, my answer is no :)